# how to find closest value in sorted array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have sorted array with numbers as keys, I need a reasonably fast alg to pick a key number which is holding value closest or identical (if exists) to given variable. If given value is higher than max or lower than min values, then keys holding max and min are given respectively.

---

so I made an attempt and here is a function that translates values in one array according to another, it can be used for example a temperature, -10 to cold or +30 to hot, but for big arrays it is not so fast, any clue how to make it faster ?

```
function transnum($nums,$transarr,$searchkey='x',$returnkey='y') {
$was_arr = is_array($nums); $nums = (array)$nums;
foreach ($nums as &$num) {
    if ($num===null or $num==='') continue;
    reset($transarr[$searchkey]);
    $ckey= key($transarr[$searchkey]);
    $closest = abs($num-current($transarr[$searchkey]));
    while($next = next($transarr[$searchkey])) {
        $checkclosest=abs($num-$next);
        if($closest>$checkclosest) {
            $closest = $checkclosest;
            $ckey = key($transarr[$searchkey]);
        }
        else break;
    }
    $num = $transarr[$returnkey][$ckey];
}
if(!$was_arr) $nums = $nums[0];
return $nums;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). The basic algorithm goes something like this, assuming you're looking for `myVal`

1. Look at the middle value of the array.
2. If the value is `myVal`, you're done.
3. If the value is higher than `myVal`, split the array in half and go to 1, but use only the bottom half of the array
4. If the value is lower, go to 1, but use only the top half.
5. Once you reach and array of length = one, compare that value to its neighbours to see which is closest.

This should be an O(log N) search.

Comment: I think that algorithm doesn't give the closest value. The closest value might be adjacent to the returned value.

Comment: a counter example is: [1, 3, 10], searching for the closest value to 4. the first middle is 3, and then the subarray [10] is considered, and 10 is returned. however, the closest value is actually 3.

Comment: I agree with lijie, but you could tweak binary search to get the nearest value: everytime, you go to a half, you include the previous checked number in the half. when your subset reaches a count of 2, you choose the closer value of the two.

Answer (score 3):

This is a java implementation, you may translate into a language of your choice.

```
static int findNearestValue(int value, int arr[], int low, int high) {
    int result = -1;
    if(high-low>1){
            int mid = (low + high)/2;
        
            if(arr[mid]>value)
                result = findNearestValue(value, arr, low, mid);
            else if(arr[mid]<value)
                result = findNearestValue(value, arr, mid, high);
            else
                result = arr[mid];
        } else
            result = abs(value-arr[low]) < abs(value-arr[high]) ? arr[low] : arr[high];
        
        return result;
}
```